# Alternative rules in PARSE with SKIP only did not output expected results

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I encounter a snippet of code:

```
blk: [1 #[none] 2 #[none] 3 #[none]]
probe parse blk [
    any [
        set s integer! (print 'integer) | (print 'none) skip
    ]
]
```

the output is:

```
integer
none
integer
none
integer
none
none
true
```

Note that in front of `true` there are two `none`s. While the next code snippet output the expected output:

```
blk: [1 #[none] 2 #[none] 3 #[none]]
probe parse blk [
    any [
        set s integer! (print 'integer) | and none! (print 'none) skip
    ]
]
```

output:

```
integer
none
integer
none
integer
none
true
```

Why the previous one could not output the same result with the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first rule should better be

```
probe parse blk [
    any [
        set s integer! (print 'integer) | skip (print 'none) 
    ]
]
```

as in your first rule you print none, if there is no integer and just skip after. This causes, that you print none even when the cursor is at the end. The skip just ends the parsing.

In your second rule the **none!** is not true at the end, so the parsing stops. It can be written shorter

```
probe parse blk [
    any [
        set s integer! (print 'integer) |  none! (print 'none) 
    ]
]
```

In your second rule the **and** does not move the cursor forward, so you need the additional skip. Without **and**  the **none!** eats one item already.